# how to receive email notification for linux server memory utilization

Tags: 13.04, monitoring

I have a critical webserevr running on Ubuntu. I need to receive email notification whenever server CPU utilization and memory utilization goes above a threshold.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a pick:

- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/)

> This is one of the most popular web based Linux monitoring systems nowadays, actually it’s industry standard for IT infrastructure monitoring. Licensed under GPL Nagios is available for everybody free of charge and allows to monitor availability and response time of network services, usage of system resources like CPU load, RAM allocation etc., number of logged in users and many-many more. It doesn’t makes sense to list here everything that can be monitored by Nagios but its nature implies that main Nagios instance (server) collects information from either local system or Nagios clients (agents). It means you can install client software on number of Linux, BSD, Windows hosts or Cisco devices, point them to Nagios server and see states of their services or processes in one place: Nagios web based monitoring tool (see the screenshot below).
>
> In case of any outage detected by Nagios server or any anomaly you will get an alert from Nagios. It’s important that Nagios suports wide range of alerts including e-mail, sms, chat messages and phone call notifications. Large number of official and third party plugins can extend Nagios’ functionality dramatically.

- [Zabbbix](http://www.zabbix.com/)

> Zabbix is enterprise class Linux monitoring system with impressive list of capabilities available out of the box. It is licensed under GPL and is written in PHP. In brief Zabbix can do the same tasks as Nagios and Cacti by default: Zabbix easily graphs monitored data and sends alerts to user in case of any problem. Using Zabbix you can create maps of the hosts, group hosts by various categories and so on.

- [Cacti](http://docs.cacti.net/). For mail it requires [thold](http://docs.cacti.net/plugin:thold).

> Cacti is another web based monitoring system written in PHP and licensed under GPL. Unlike Nagios describe above Cacti was designed mainly fo the graphs — in brief, Cacti polls various services and then graphs resulting data. It uses RRDTool to build graphs so if you can some graphs in .rrd files you can easily attach them to Cacti and have everything in one place.
>
> So you can see CPU load graphs, RAM usage, round trip time stats, bandwidth utilization and much more information collected from various hosts. As well as Nagios Cacti supports SNMP that makes it possible to monitor almost any device in your network: Linux hosts, *BSD hosts, Windows hosts, Cisco devices, Juniper equipment, voip phones, routers, switches whatever.
>
> Meantime by default Cacti doesn’t provides alerts so you should install third party plugin (thold or others) for that or use more flexible solutions supporting alerts (like Nagios or Zabbix).

[Source](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/03/22/linux-monitoring-tools/).